# AWS SNS and React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-sns

I've been trying to connect to AWS SNS using react native.

I know the React Native AWS SDK is out (sort of)... But I'm at a lost with the instructions to get started along with Cognito.

I've tried writing generating my own signature but that's been challenging (using v2 and v4 signature). My signature's haven't been matching :(.
I've also tried using react-native-aws-signature (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-aws-signature).

Any suggestions, on what's the best approach? Perhaps I've been generating my signature incorrectly?